# How do I sort a collection of a collection of Strings?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a dataset which has colections of Strings like:

```
[dog, cat, bear]
[ant,                 ++salamander]
[     ---@cat]
```

etc.

I need to take all of these collections of strings, and parse them to remove random characters and whitespace. Then I need to sort them individually, as well as sort them against each other.

In the end, the output should be:

```
[ant, salamander]
[bear, cat, dog]
[cat]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You can use method [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) to get rid of the random characters and whitespace.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code, how exactly your data is structured?